# Return async await try/catch thrown Error in ExpressJS response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

Using ExpressJS `4.16.0`, and NodeJS `10.15.0`, and KnexJS/Bookshelf, I'm trying to figure out error handling.

Errors are being caught as expected in my application, but the error is not being returned in the response from the server call: `return res.status(400).send(error);`, instead I'm getting a `{}`.

How can I fix this?

**user route:**

```
router.post('/users/register',
  async function(req, res, next) {

    let user;

    try {
        user = await UserService.register(req.body);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Route: Catch: ', error); // Will display error from UserService Error here: "column users.emailll does not exist"

        return res.status(400).send(error); // Sends `{}` back
    }
    ...
```

**UsersService:**

```
...

try {
    user = await new User.User({
        emailll: userInput.email // Will throw error in "catch" below because "emailll" is invalid field
    }).fetch();
} catch (error) {
    // Throws error "column users.emailll does not exist"
    console.log('Service: Catch: ', error);
    throw new Error(error);
}
```

Response from server: `{}`

I'm assuming the error is being swallowed somewhere due to `async await` calls? Do I need to use something like [this express-async-errors](https://github.com/davidbanham/express-async-errors) lib?

Comment: BTW `throw new Error(error);` could be just `throw error;`

Answer (score 2):

`res.send(err)` will internally attempt to convert that object to JSON.  By default, `JSON.stringify(obj)` only includes enumerable properties on the target object and the usual properties you look for on an error object are not enumerable by default.

A work-around would be to make a copy of the object with whichever properties you want to send and assigning them normally will default to enumerable:

```
let obj = {filename: error.filename, message: error.message};
res.send(obj);
```

In general, you don't want to send internal detail about your server back as an error message so usually, you would hide the implementation detail and send a message that might be more useful to the client.

So, perhaps you just want to to do:

```
res.status(500).send(error.message);
```

If you really want ALL the properties from the `err` object, you could also use a helper function like this:

```
function makeEnumerableCopy() {
    let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(err);
    // set all properties in the descriptor to be enumerable
    for (let key of Object.keys(descriptor)) {
        descriptor[key].enumerable = true;
    }
    return Object.defineProperties({}, descriptor);
}
```

that will make a shallow copy of the object and make all "own" properties be enumerable so you could then use it with `res.send()` or `JSON.stringify()` and get all the properties.

```
res.send(makeEnumerableCopy(err));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try sending error message instead of error stack

```
return res.status(400).send(error.message);
```